# What's the difference between no{option} and inv{option} in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I read the documentation and I can't figure out what makes them different.

> :se[t] no{option} Toggle option: Reset, switch it off.
>
> ---
>
> :se[t] {option}! or :se[t] inv{option}
>
> Toggle option: Invert value. {not in Vi}

For example, I thought that if I used `:set noic` therefore I shouldn't be able to `:set invic` because the option is disabled altogether as there's nothing to invert.

But apparently, you can still invert it.

Answer (score 1):

"Invert" means make it the opposite of what it is now — turn it on if it's off, or off if it's on.